# View multiple text files in TreeView and DataGridView

Tags: c#, datagridview, treeview

I want to load several text files in a folder into a TreeView. The selected text file in TreeView should be displayed with the values in DataGridView.

For example:

```
 TreeView
    └── Folder
        ├── Text1.txt
        ├── Text2.txt
        ├── Text3.txt
        ├── Text4.txt
        └── Text5.txt
```

The text files can always look different. For example like this:

```
ColumnTitle1 ; ColumnTitle2 (always depends how often in the first line ";" is applied.)
      Value1 ; Value2
      Value1 ; Value2
```

This is my current code for reading the text file with an OpenFileDialog:

```
OpenFileDialog openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
openFileDialog.ShowDialog();
StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(openFileDialog.FileName);
while (!streamReader.EndOfStream)
{
    string[] stringArray = streamReader.ReadLine().Split(';');
    dataGridView1.Rows.Add("All values in the stringArray that are separated by ';'");
}
streamReader.Close();


SaveFileDialog saveFileDialog = new SaveFileDialog();
saveFileDialog.ShowDialog();
StreamWriter streamReader = new StreamWriter(saveFileDialog.FileName);
for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
{
    sw.WriteLine(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString() + ";" + dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value.ToString());
}
streamReader.Close();
```

Does anyone have an example of how I can read out the first line and dynamically embed the Columns into the DataGridView and edit and save them in the same text file?

Thanks to everyone who helps me with the housework